# Unable to render image from Oracle BLOB, data from BLOB is consistently 28 bytes larger

Tags: c#, html, oracle

I am trying to save an image to an oracle table within a BLOB field, later use it to display the image on a web page. For some reason when i retrieve the image data its consistently exactly 28 bytes larger than the original.

1. I load the image from the file using:

```cs
return Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename));
```

2. Save the image in a memory stream, then convert to array:

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();

imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);

return ms.ToArray();
```

3. Insert the data into the table: (Note I have tried both ODBC and Oracle)

```cs
var Isql = $"INSERT INTO PAS_IMAGE_TEST (PROD_DATE, IMAGE_DATA) VALUES
     (TO_DATE('...','...'), :IMAGE_DATA)";

var cmdI = new OracleCommand(Isql, cn);

var pI = cmdI.Parameters.Add("IMAGE_DATA", OracleDbType.Blob);                    

pI.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

pI.Value = byteArrayIn;

cmdI.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

4. This seems to work, the row is there.
5. I select the data:

```cs
var Isql = $"SELECT IMAGE_DATA FROM PAS_IMAGE_TEST WHERE PROD_DATE = TO_DATE('{ProdDate.ToString(common_database.CS_DATEFORMAT)}','{common_database.OR_DATEFORMAT}')";

var cmd = new OracleCommand(Isql, cn);

return cmd.ExecuteScalar(); - returns first rows/first column afaik.
```

6. Convert the object to a bytearray:

```cs
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

7. Convert it to a B64 url:

```cs
return $"data:image/{fileType};charset=utf-8;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

8. Supplying this string to an html src should display the image. It doesn't... fact is that if I used to original byte array (data from step 2) prior to saving it works expected.

Comment: I am not catching here, why do you need the binary formatter?. do `ExecuteReader...  if (reader.Read() reader.GetBytes(.....)` You will have to prepare buffer there and then retrieve how many bytes returned and then take the actual subset  [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#ODPNT1185)

Comment: You can query `lengthb(image_data)` to see the size stored in the DB - if you need to narrow down if the problem is during storage or retrieval.

Comment: phew... what a relief